# Servicenow: substitute for $sp.getRecord() in scoped app

Tags: angularjs, widget, servicenow, server-side-scripting

In a global application within ServiceNow, you can access the current record by using $sp.getRecord(); However, that's not available in a scoped environment. Is there a substitute way to access the current record in a scoped application?

Here is the code I'm trying to scope below:

```
var gr = $sp.getRecord();
if (gr == null)
    return;

data.tableLabel = gr.getLabel();
data.table = gr.getTableName();
data.sys_id = gr.getUniqueValue();
data.status = gr.state.getValue();
data.name = gr.name.getDisplayValue();
data.team_lead = gr.team_leader.getDisplayValue();
data.code = gr.project_charge_code.getDisplayValue();
```

Comment: "To access the current record"- in what kind of script? where?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a widget for the Service Portal. I believe you should be able to use `$sp.getRecord()` in a scoped application. According to the [API Reference](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/api_doc?v=jakarta&id=server):

> **Please note**: The APIs below are intended for scoped applications and
>   may behave differently in the global scope.

However, if you have troubles still, one way is to query it as a `GlideRecord` if you have a way to reference it.

```
var gr = new GlideRecord('x_abcd_my_table');
gr.addQuery('number', 'XMT001245');
gr.query();

while (gr.next()) {
    data.tableLabel = gr.getLabel();
    data.table = gr.getTableName();
    data.sys_id = gr.getUniqueValue();
    data.status = gr.state.getValue();
    data.name = gr.name.getDisplayValue();
    data.team_lead = gr.team_leader.getDisplayValue();
    data.code = gr.project_charge_code.getDisplayValue();
}
```

Comment: Hey Kirk, thanks for this!  To follow up on this, how would you query the current record you're on.  For example, the addQuery line, how would you dynamically query the record that's currently open?  Not sure if this makes sense to you or not.  Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how you are loading the record. What are you doing to get to the record?

Comment: `$sp.getParameter('table')` and `$sp.getParameter('sys_id')`: `var grTask = new GlideRecord($sp.getParameter('table')); grTask.get($sp.getParameter('sys_id'))`